# Ubuntu 20.10 No SSID in Wifi Scan

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

I have an usb dongle realtek 8188eu .I installed it from git. then wifi appears in gnome.
but there is no ssid while it was scaning.

```
 *-network ETKİSİZLEŞTİRİLDİ
       açıklama: Kablosuz arayüz
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:7
       mantıksal ad: wlx00e020301740
       serial: 00:e0:20:30:17:40
       kapasiteler: eternet physical wireless
       yapılandırma: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu driverversion=5.8.0-29-generic multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

wlx00e020301740  unassociated  ESSID:""  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0





[   89.276146] kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver r8188eu
[   89.279808] kernel: r8188eu 1-8:1.0 wlx00e020301740: renamed from wlan0
[   89.300047] kernel: cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[   89.300274] kernel: cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[   89.316483] kernel: R8188EU: Firmware Version 11, SubVersion 1, Signature 0x88e1
[   90.706425] kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nva8_fuc084 failed with error -2
[   90.706434] kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nva8_fuc084d failed with error -2
[   90.706435] kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: unable to load firmware data
[   90.706445] kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: init failed, -19
[   92.312947] kernel: rfkill: input handler disabled
```

What can I do for my wifi connection?

Answer (score 0):

I change wifi adapter . it solved.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/kablosuz

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install rtl8188fu-dkms
```